# Cron Jobs php doesn't load php.ini

Tags: php, cron

I'm working with a file in .php that is totally debugged when I lunch it browser.

The problem comes with TERMINAL and cron jobs.

For ex. in the beginning of the php page, I load a database with MySQLi but what I receive back is an error telling "Cannot instantiate non-existing class: mysqli in ...".

The way I run script from cron job file is:

```
 /usr/bin/php4.4 /[..path..]/dbmoninsprimera.php
```

I'm almost sure is a matter of php.ini (because MySQLi shouldn't be loaded with server?) but don't really know how to call collectedly all "standard scripts" that are loaded in browser, but clearly are not loaded from command line.

Do you think you can help me?

Thx.

Alberto

**UPDATE v. 1.0**

here is extract from phpinfo():

[php.ini-1 http://esimeconomytools.altervista.org/a.png](http://esimeconomytools.altervista.org/a.png)

[php.ini-2 http://esimeconomytools.altervista.org/b.png](http://esimeconomytools.altervista.org/b.png)

[php.ini-3 http://esimeconomytools.altervista.org/c.png](http://esimeconomytools.altervista.org/c.png)

**UPDATE v. 2.0 - SOLUTION**

Here we go.
As always solution is easier than question.

The correct way to run CRON JOB (at least on 1&1 Servers) is not:

```
 /usr/bin/php4.4 /[..path..]/dbmoninsprimera.php
```

but:

```
 20 5,11,17,23 * * * php5.5 /[..path..]/dbmoninsprimera.php
```

the point was that I wasn't calling the correct php version with php.ini and so on.
Simply writing:

```
 20 5,11,17,23 * * * php /[..path..]/dbmoninsprimera.php
```

was incorrect.
So I had to call "php5.5" in spite of "php".

Thanks for your time and attention.
Sorry for delay.

Alberto

Comment: There's a different `php.ini` for CLI and webserver.

Comment: Make sure the CLI version of `php.ini` loads all the extensions you need.

Comment: how do I check it? Sorry for stupid question, but I'm not really expert with terminal a php server...

Comment: maybe I've solved and solution seems really easy. Hold on pls

Comment: Holding on ever since! what did you find?

Comment: true sorry, I update question

Comment: 1) Running PHP/4.4 is like driving a Ford T, but far less pleasant. The mere fact that your hosting service supports it is really scary. 2) If you run `phpinfo()` through a web server you won't get CLI settings. You can try `php -i > /path/to/a/writable/directory/phpinfo.txt` and read the file afterwards.

Comment: thx Alvaro for your answer, but I discovered the solution.
and it was really really simple (pls check question end for solution that worked for me).